# How can I check if haptic feedback enabled in system on Android 13 or higher?

Tags: android, kotlin, deprecated, android-vibration, haptic-feedback

I'm trying to get if haptic feedback enabled in System Settings, i.e. globally on a device. I don't need to set this setting, just read.

We do it this way on Android 12 or lower:

```
Settings.System.getInt(context.contentResolver, Settings.System.HAPTIC_FEEDBACK_ENABLED) == 1
```

**But with the release of Android 13 Google deprecated flag** `HAPTIC_FEEDBACK_ENABLED`. Now it recommended to use `android.os.VibrationAttributes.USAGE_TOUCH`.
It's really incomprehensible how to use it.

I need something like this:

```
 val hapticEnabled: Boolean
     get() = if (BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
         // here what I'm trying to find out
     } else {
         Settings.System.getInt(context.contentResolver, Settings.System.HAPTIC_FEEDBACK_ENABLED) == 1
     }
```

Comment: No, unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

In the new Android Version (13 or higher) you can use VibrationManager to check this, please check below:

```
val hapticEnabled: Boolean
    get() {
        return if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
            val vibratorManager = requireContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_MANAGER_SERVICE) as VibratorManager
            val vibrator = vibratorManager.defaultVibrator

            vibrator.hasVibrator()
        } else {
            Settings.System.getInt(requireContext().contentResolver, Settings.System.HAPTIC_FEEDBACK_ENABLED) == 1
        }
    }
```

Comment: With vibrator.hasVibrator() I can check if the hardware as a vibrator, not if the haptic feedback enabled in system settings.

Comment: For the older phone check, you'll want to use the convenience method (provides default value) `Settings.System.getInt(requireContext().contentResolver, Settings.System.HAPTIC_FEEDBACK_ENABLED, 0) == 1)` to handle phones that don't have this setting without throwing an exception.